# Access file using MVC 6 .NET Core with ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am calling this function to send a file via post:

```
function AddFileHandler() {
        return $.ajax({
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("AddFile", "SomeController")',
            data: getFile()
        })
    }
```

In my controller, there is this method which produces an error on the first line:

```
[HttpPost]
public string AddFile()
{
    var attachedFile = Request.Form.Files["CsvDoc"]; // there is an error of wrong contentType
    return "";
}
```

My getFile method optains data like this:

```
function getFile() {
    var input = document.getElementById("csvFile");
    if (!input || !input.files || !input.files[0]) {
        return ";";
    }
    console.log(input.files[0]); //inputs my file correctly
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("CsvDoc", input.files[0]);
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? Does it matter what is in the html?

Comment: You also never return anything other than `;` from your `getFile()`. I assume you wanted to return `data`?

Comment: If I put `"multipart/form-data"` as content type I am getting `System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'Missing content-type boundary.'` exception.

Comment: @TJWolschon that is only null check, if I have any file in my input. If not it returns `;`

Comment: Yes but then you never return the data even if it's not null.

Comment: @TJWolschon you're absolutely right, I am just getting too stupid overtime...

Comment: @TJWolschon can you just post it as an answer? it works that way

Comment: Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting to return anything from `getFile()`

simply add

```
return data;
```